# get the maximal length of LFSR

Tags: c

I want help pls to identify what is wrong with that C code , I want to test the maximal length of a linear feedback shift register (LFSR), so first I take a copy of the original register then I shift the copy and then test its equality with the original one and so on till get the maximal length.

Below is the code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<malloc.h>


void shiftLFSR (unsigned char* LFSR, unsigned char ntabs, unsigned char* tabs, unsigned char  length);
void test_the_equality (unsigned char* LFSR, unsigned char* original_LFSR, unsigned char length, unsigned char count, unsigned char main_flag);

int main(){


    unsigned char length;
    unsigned char *LFSR;
    unsigned char *original_LFSR;
    unsigned char i;
    unsigned char ntabs;
    unsigned char *tabs;
    unsigned char count;
    unsigned char main_flag;
    count = 1;
    main_flag = 1;
    printf("enter the length of the LFSR\n");
    scanf("%d", &length);
    printf("enter the number of Tabs\n");
    scanf("%d", &ntabs);
    LFSR = (unsigned char *) malloc(length * sizeof(unsigned char));
    original_LFSR = (unsigned char *) malloc(length * sizeof(unsigned char));   
    tabs = (unsigned char *) malloc(ntabs * sizeof(unsigned char));



    for (i = 0; i < ntabs; i++){
    printf("enter the position of Tab[%d]\n",i);
    scanf("%d", &tabs[i]);
    }

    original_LFSR[0] = 0;
    printf("LFSR[0] = %d\n",original_LFSR[0]);

    for (i = 1; i < length; i++){
        original_LFSR[i] =  original_LFSR[i-1] ^ 1;
            printf("LFSR[%d] = %d\n",i, original_LFSR[i]);
    }
    for ( i = 0; i < length; i++)
            LFSR [i] = original_LFSR[i];

    while (main_flag == 1){     
    shiftLFSR (LFSR, ntabs, tabs, length);
    test_the_equality(LFSR, original_LFSR, length, &count, &main_flag);         
    }

    printf("the length of period = %d", count);
    free (LFSR);
    return 0;
}





void shiftLFSR (unsigned char LFSR[], unsigned char ntabs, unsigned char tabs[], unsigned char  length){
    unsigned char feedback_value;
    unsigned char *Temp_LFSR;
    unsigned char i;

    feedback_value = 0;
    Temp_LFSR = (unsigned char *) malloc(length * sizeof(unsigned char));
    for (i = 0; i < ntabs; i++)
            feedback_value ^= LFSR[tabs[i]];

    for (i = 0; i < (length - 1); i++)
        Temp_LFSR [i+1] = LFSR[i];

    Temp_LFSR[0] = feedback_value;

    for ( i = 0; i < length; i++)
        LFSR [i] = Temp_LFSR[i];
    free (Temp_LFSR);
} 



void test_the_equality (unsigned char LFSR[], unsigned char original_LFSR[], unsigned char length, unsigned char *count, unsigned char *main_flag){
    unsigned char i;
    i = 0;
    while (i < length){

        if (LFSR[i] == original_LFSR[i])

            i++;
        else{
            *count = *count +1;
            printf("the length of the first period = %d", *count);
            break;

        }

    }
    if (i >= length - 1)
        *main_flag = 0;

}
```

Comment: What output do you get, and how is it different from what you expect?

Comment: If there is no tab on the highest bit of your LFSR, you are not guaranteed to return to the original LFSR and thus you may end up in an infinite loop.

Comment: If you are using `gcc` then use the `-Wall` option, as there are some typing errors + the prototype of `test_the_equality` doesn't match its declaration. But after fixing everything I think you will find that the test `i >= length - 1` in `test_the_equality` should be `i >= length`. You should also consider to at least change `count` to an `int`, because otherwise it will overflow on even small LFSRs.

Comment: If you are interested in tab combinations yielding the maximal length, then look into primitive polynomials and in particular the work from Sean Erik O'Connor: http://www.seanerikoconnor.freeservers.com/Mathematics/AbstractAlgebra/PrimitivePolynomials/overview.html